# How to get tags in Behat FeatureContext

Tags: php, testing, behat

Is there a way how to get tags for a scenario in Behat FeatureContext in which the method is being run in?

#### my.feature

```
  @SPRF1
  Scenario: My scenario
    Given something is done
```

#### FeatureContext

```
class FeatureContext implements \Behat\Behat\Context\Context
{
    /**
     * @Then something is done
     */
    public function somethingIsDone()
    {
        $tags = $this->getScenarioTags(); // this doesn't exist
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `BeforeScenarioScope` hook.
Try something like this:

```
    /**
     * @BeforeScenario
     */
    public function getTestId(BeforeScenarioScope $scope)
    {
        $tags = $scope->getScenario()->getTags();
    }
```

Don't forget to add `use Behat\Behat\Hook\Scope\BeforeScenarioScope;`